# How can a unqualified-id contain a unqualified-name in a function call?

Tags: c++, function, language-lawyer, lookup

In C++ draft ISO(N4901/2021) 6.5.4 (Argument-dependent name lookup) we have:

> When the postfix-expression in a function call (7.6.1.3) is an
> unqualified-id, and unqualified lookup (6.5.3) for the name in the
> unqualified-id does not find any
> (1.1) — declaration of a class
> member, or (1.2) — function declaration inhabiting a block scope, or
> (1.3) — declaration not of a function or function template

I can't figure out a example of an *unqualified-id* that contains a *unqualified name*(with the two being different). Draft gives the following example, but i couldn't say what is what in the `(f)(s)`:

```
namespace N {
struct S { };
void f(S);
}
void g() {
N::S s;
f(s); // OK: calls N::f
(f)(s); // error: N::f not considered; parentheses prevent argument-dependent lookup
}
```

Comment: I think if you make `f` a function template: `template<typename T> T f(S);` (and call it like `f<int>(s);`), then you'll have lookup for the name (which is `f`) in the _unqualified-id_ (which is `f<int>`) where name ≠ _unqualified-id_

Comment: I think the wording misses the word «component», i.e. it shall say _and unqualified lookup  for the **component** name in the unqualified-id …_ See http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.unqual#def:component_name and http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#2

Comment: _I can't figure out a example of an unqualified-id that contains a unqualified name_ Also, where is «unqualified name» in the wording you cite?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer, shouldn't it be a unqualified name since occurs a unqualified lookup first?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer. You asked me where is the <<unqualified name>> in the wording I cited. In fact what I cited don't say it, it says just "name". But I suposed that this "name" would be, necessarily, a unqualified name. My assumption is wrong?

Comment: Well, a name would be unqualified, but since the wording should say «component name» (waiting for an answer from Davis Herring), there is not much space left for «unqualified».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't figure out a example of an unqualified-id that contains a unqualified name(with the two being different).

The wording doesn't say «unqualified name». And seem to miss the word «component» before «name».

Here is an example:

```cpp
namespace N
{
    struct S { };
    template<typename>
    void f(S);
}

void g()
{
    N::S s;
    f<int>(s); // OK: ADL finds N::f
}
```

An *unqualified-id* here is `f<int>` (which is a *template-id*) and the lookup is performed for its (component) name `f`.

---

[[expr.prim.id.unqual]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.unqual#2):

> A [*component name*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.unqual#def:component_name) of an *unqualified-id* *U* is
> — *U* if it is a name or
> — the component name of the *template-id* or *type-name* of *U*, if any.

[[temp.names]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#2)

> The component name of a *simple-template-id*, *template-id*, or *template-name* is the first name in it.

The term «name» is defined in [[basic.pre]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.pre#4):

> A [*name*](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.pre#def:name) is an *identifier* ([lex.name]), *operator-function-id* ([over.oper]), *literal-operator-id* ([over.literal]), or *conversion-function-id* ([class.conv.fct]).